# I am getting double output from a php loop

Tags: php, csv, fgetcsv

My data is outputting twice and I am not to sure why. It should be one fname and lname per line.

```
<?php

$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("nameList1.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
    while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "    ")) !== FALSE) {
        $num = count($data);
        //$result = explode($data);
        echo "<br />\n";
        $row++;
        for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
                //echo $data[$c];
                echo $data[0];
                echo " ";
                echo $data[1];
        }
    }
    fclose($handle);
}
```

*******   *output*   *****************

```
Nancy AlvordNancy Alvord
Lucy HadacLucy Hadac
Laura LundgrenLaura Lundgren
Judy PigottJudy Pigott
Thomas BayleyThomas Bayley
Barbara BrownBarbara Brown
Aaron DixonAaron Dixon
Jennifer HadlockJennifer Hadlock
Molly AdolfsonMolly Adolfson
Susan AnsteadSusan Anstead
Shannon BraddockShannon Braddock
Isa Dâ€™ArleansIsa Dâ€™Arleans
Elizabeth DavisElizabeth Davis
William DonnellyWilliam Donnelly
```

Comment: I don't think you need the for().

Comment: Remove the inner for loop and then try again.

Comment: You don't need the inner loop

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[0] . " " . $data[1];
}
```

As you have 2 differents data per line (fname, lname) $num is always equal to 2.

So twice, you will print out $data[0] & $data[1] ;)

You juste have to do :

```
echo $data[0];
echo $data[0];
```

Or if you absolutely want to use the for statement :

```
for ($c=0; $c < $num; $c++) {
    echo $data[$c] . " ";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$row = 1;
if (($handle = fopen("nameList1.txt", "r")) !== FALSE) {
while (($data = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, "    ")) !== FALSE) {
    $num = count($data);
    //$result = explode($data);
    echo "<br />\n";
    $row++;
    echo $data[0];
    echo " ";
    echo $data[1];
}
fclose($handle);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You are getting all the csv fields two times because , the forloop inside the while loop is starting from 0 to  , it should be 1 to  or 0 to

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
$file = $_FILES[csv][tmp_name]; 
    $handle = fopen($file,"r"); 

    //loop through the csv file and insert into database 
    do { 
        if ($data[0]) { 
            $record['contact_email'] = $data[2];
            $record['subject'] = $_REQUEST['subject'];
            $record['message'] = $_REQUEST['message'];
            $record['status'] = 0;

            $oAdminEmail->insertQueEmail($record);
            } 
    } while ($data = fgetcsv($handle,1000,",","'"));
```